# Calculate theoretical forward price of a stock

Tags: forward

The current price of a stock is USD400 per share and it pays no dividends. Assuming a constant interest rate of $8% $ compounded quarterly, what is the stock's theoretical forward price for delivery in $9$ months ?

I am taking the Financial Engineering and risk management course on Coursera. The above question was in the quiz and I got a wrong answer on it.

Shouldn't the answer be: $$400\times\left(1+\frac{0.08}{4}\right)^3 = 424.48\, ?$$

Comment: What was the given answer? At a quick glance, your approach looks like.

Comment: The answer is 400*(1+0.08/4)^3 = 424.48.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use a no-arbitrage argument.  Assume that the (continuously compounding) dividend yield is $q$ while the interest rate is $r$.

For portfolio 1, we go long 1 forward contract with maturity $T$ and delivery price $K$.  The payoff at time $T$ is $S_T - K$.

For portfolio 2, we go long $e^{-qT}$ unit of a stock (while reinvest all dividends) and short $K e^{-rT}$ unit of a bond.  The payoff at time $T$ is also $S_T - K$.

At time $t = 0$, the present value (PV) of portfolio 1 is 0, because we just entered the trade.  The PV of portfolio 2 at time $t = 0$ is $S_0 e^{-qT} - K e^{-rT}$.  Assuming that there is no arbitrage, we conclude that the PV at time $t = 0$ of portfolios 1 and 2 must be the same: $ S_0 e^{-qT} - K e^{-rT} = 0$.  Hence $\boxed{K = S_0 e^{(r-q)T}}$.  Your answer of $400 (1+0.08/4)^3=424.48$ is correct.

Comment: Is it possible to create a portfolio like portfolio 2 in reality? In other words, could one buy or sell a fraction of the stock or a fraction of a bond?

Answer (score 0):

It should be just $400*(1+0.02)^3$
Where $0.02$ is quarterly compounded rate for a quarter, and
$n$ is 3 quarters, hence the exponent 3

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. J.Hull's book explains it clearly in Chapter 3, paragraph 3.5 "Forward price for an investment asset". It is also shows the arbitrage strategy if the price does not match.

Comment: Hi LorenzoQF, welcome to Quant.SE! Could you please give a more specific reference? All of Hull is quite a read.

Comment: Chapter 3. Paragraph 3.5 "Forward price for an investment asset". It is also shown the arbitrage strategy if the price does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Based on No Arbitrage equation for Forward Asset combination:
$S_0 e^{−qT} − K e^{−rT} = 0$

i.e. $K = S_0 e^{(r-q)T} \\
        = 400 * e^{(0.02 - 0) * 3} \\
        = 400 * 1.061837 \\
        = 424.7346$

Answer (score -1):

Assuming 8% is the quartely interest rate

I think it's: $400*(1+0.08)^3 = 503.8$

$0.08$ is the quarter interest rate and you compound for 3 quarters

**Or**

$ r_{year} = (1+0.08)^4 - 1 = 0.36 $

$400*(1+0.36)^(9/12) = 503.8$

Because there are 9 months in a 12-month year.

Comment: At a quick glance, this doesn't look correct. The quarterly rate would be annualized when it's quoted so a quarterly rate of .08 is .08/4

Comment: Yes, but how do you know if it's annualized or quarterly? It the question is not expressed that it's annualized

Comment: It is a standard convention to annualized rates, such that they would have to specify if the rate were not annualized.